# reset auto-increment when exporting only structure

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I try to export table structure using phpMyAdmin, it keeps last auto-increment value.

Is it possible to say to phpMyAdmin not to do it and reset it to zero?
(directly, without later editing .sql file)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to export the structure only, not data, in which case there is a workaround you may use but it's not a perfect solution. You can disable the auto increment  entirely and manually re-add it once you've completely the import. Within phpMyAdmin, you can reset the next auto increment value, but when exporting it's not possible to keep the auto increment property while modifying the value. To accomplish what you're trying to do, you'll have to settle for either manually editing the file to change the value to 0 as you've been doing, or completing the export/import without the auto increment property and turning on auto increment after the export (by editing the SQL file to add that line) or after import (by modifying the recreated table structure).

Comment: It's too bad, that phpMyAdmin doesn't have such option by default. I just posted a feature-request on their sourceforge page: https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/feature-requests/1549/